# sending email using java with javamail

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

Here's what Im doing to send the email

**EDITED CODE**

```
 public class EmailAlerts{



public  static Session session=null;
public static final  String fromAddr="from@gmail.com";
public static final   String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
public static final String password="dfd";
public static  MimeMessage message= null;

public EmailAlerts() {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

     session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(fromAddr,password);
            }
        });

}

/**
 * @param args  
 * 
 * 
 */



public static void sendNotification( String toAddress)
{

    try {

         message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddr));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                 new InternetAddress(toAddress));
        message.setSubject("Exchange Rate Notification!");
        message.setText("The best rates are :");//+body. Need to add date from the Map/List with the rates in descending order!

        Transport.send(message);

    } 


    catch ( MessagingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //Need to write a custom exception handler
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sendNotification("toAddr@gm.com");
    System.out.println("Done!");

}
```

However, I get an exception at Line 50 saying that the SMTP host is trying to connect to localhost

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25, response: 421

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1270)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at com.business.alerts.EmailAlerts.sendNotification(EmailAlerts.java:50)
    at com.business.alerts.EmailAlerts.main(EmailAlerts.java:64)
```

when Im actually trying to connect to gmail.

Any thoughts?

Comment: To anyone who got this far.. the problem was that I didnt invoke the constructor(which was doing the initialization).  Cant delete the question now :(.

Comment: If you have found the problem then please post it as an answer, and accept it, to help anyone else that may have the same problem. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The property `mail.smtp.port` should be set to 465.

Comment: I don't think you can set the properties using the instance of `System.getProperties` like you do. Check the example #2 there : http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

Answer (score -1):

I am using the exact code that you have shown in your question as well in one of my app and it works perfectly fine.

However the only difference that I see is, I am using a valid "from" address with a valid password. The only other reason that I can think of is outgoing traffic on port 465 is blocked on your system, but the error code that you have shown doesn't suggest that either.

`421    <domain> Service not available, closing transmission channel`

May be you can try using a valid "from" address and see if that works for you.

Comment: Used a valid from address/password combo. But the error persists

Comment: On looking again at your code, I see that you are initializing the `session` in the constructor, but I don't see you creating the object of `EmailAlerts` class which should actually initialize the `session` object by calling the constructor.